# How to load pre-trained LDA model to Jupiter Notebook?

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook, gensim, lda

I trained the LDA model on my PC and saved it locally by using model.save() command. I can load this model and output topics in PyCharm, but when I try to load the same model in Jupiter Notebook I get an error.

Did anyone encounter the same problem and fix it?
Below is the full error output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-043e6d6083e2> in <module>
      1 # Loading saved model
----> 2 model = models.LdaModel.load('information_extraction/optimal_LDA3.model')
      3 # model_topics = model.show_topics(formatted=True)
      4 # pprint.pprint(model.print_topics(num_words=15))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py in load(cls, fname, *args, **kwargs)
   1636         """
   1637         kwargs['mmap'] = kwargs.get('mmap', None)
-> 1638         result = super(LdaModel, cls).load(fname, *args, **kwargs)
   1639 
   1640         # check if `random_state` attribute has been set after main pickle load

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py in load(cls, fname, mmap)
    424         compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)
    425 
--> 426         obj = unpickle(fname)
    427         obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
    428         logger.info("loaded %s", fname)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py in unpickle(fname)
   1382         # Because of loading from S3 load can't be used (missing readline in smart_open)
   1383         if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
-> 1384             return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
   1385         else:
   1386             return _pickle.loads(f.read())

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random._pickle'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
The issue was a difference in numpy versions. I trained the LDA model on numpy==1.17.0, then I installed Anaconda and ran Jupiter with numpy==1.16.4.